# Extending image field to support additional content

Tags: 7, entities, media, database

We need to add a field to the standard Drupal Image field. This field will be used to store an id number of that particular image (so we can display a link to that image on the service: flickr, shutterstock, whatever).

We already have thousands of images stored across three different image fields. Would it be more efficient to alter the schema of the standard image field (how would we even do that?), or would it be better to setup a custom image field and migrate all of the content to the new field?

Comment: Would [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) be an option? It'd remove the need for any code and you'd still get the same effect

Comment: whoa.. well, it would have been nice to know about from the get go, but it doesn't look like it will migrate data from existing fields?

Comment: 'Fraid not, you'd have to migrate the content manually (through code would obviously be a lot faster)